# Summation over integers satisfying some conditions

Tags: summation, subset

$n$ is a fixed positive integer and $p$ is the largest prime $\le n$:

```
p = Prime[PrimePi[n]]
```

For each subset $L$ of positive composite integers less than or equal to $n$--i.e., for each element $L$ of:

```
Subsets[Select[Range[n], CompositeQ]]
```

I would like to sum $\sum \frac{1}{i}$ over all positive integers $i$ such that

(i) $i$ has no prime factor larger than $p$:

```
FactorInteger[i][[-1, 1]] <= p
```

and

(ii)

```
j/GCD(i,j)
```

is composite for each $j\in L$.

How can I incorporate (i) and (ii) into a sum given $L$?

Update: The fact that are are infinitely many $i$'s corresponding to each $L$ may cause difficulty. Perhaps I can find all $i$ satisfying (i) and (ii) where $i$ is bounded above by some $N$?

Comment: What is the magnitude of `n` you want to test? The number of subsets grows quite rapidly... Moreover, are you sure that there will be _any_ `i` satisfying your conditions?

Comment: Btw.: `:=` is not the way to set a variable (e.g., `p`) in Mathematica. Better use `p = Prime[PrimePi[n]]` (have a look at the documentation about `SetDelayed` and what it does).

Comment: I would like to test many values of `n`, but perhaps I'd like to start with 28 (since I've resolved the problem for smaller `n`). Yes, there will always be `i`'s; for example, we can always take `i=1` since then `j/GCD(1,j) = j` is composite for each `j` in `L`.

Comment: And can there be another, nontrivial `i`? Otherwise, this going to be a very expensive way to compute many ones. Maybe you should give a detailed example for some `n` in the question. This is a task in which one has to invest quite a lot of effort and people won't attack it without knowing that this will lead somewhere...

Comment: Since composite numbers only have prime factors `<= n/2`, any `i` consisting only of primes greater than or equal to `n/2` will always work. E.g., if `n=12`, then for any choice of `L`, any `j` in `L` has no prime factor larger than 5. So any `i` of the form `i=7^a*11^b` will work since the `GCD` will always be 1. This furnishes infinitely many values of `i`. For more examples of `i`, it will depend on the set `L`.

Comment: Are the elements of $L$ integers or sets of integers? if the latter, what do you exactly mean by $j\in L$?

Comment: $L$ is a set consisting of composite integers, and $j$ is a composite integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated to fix a bug pointed out by DanielLichtblau**

The restriction $\frac{j}{\gcd(j, i)}$ is composite means that $j$ must contain at least two prime factors not in $i$. The following function encodes this restriction:

```
restriction[n_] := With[{fi=FactorInteger[n]},
    Total[Ramp[#2-f[#1]]& @@@ fi] >= 2
]
```

For example:

```
restriction[12]
```

> Ramp[2 - f[2]] + Ramp[1 - f[3]] >= 2

The above says that the prime factorization of $i$ can have no factor of 2 (and any power of 3), or it can have 1 factor of 2 and no factor of 3. Applying this restriction for each element of $L$, and also specifying that the exponents must be nonnegative yields:

```
allowed[set_List] := With[{restrict = restriction /@ set},
    With[{ff = Cases[restrict, _f, Infinity] //Union},
        Reduce[And @@ restrict && And @@ Thread[ff >= 0], ff, Integers]
    ]
]
```

For example:

```
allowed[{4, 12, 21}]
```

> f[2] == 0 && f[3] == 0 && f[7] == 0

This says that the exponents of 2, 3 and 7 must be 0, but the remaining exponents are not restricted. So, the set of elements $i$ consists of:

```
5^a 11^b 13^c 17^d 19^e 23^f
```

for all nonnegative integers $a, b, c, d, e,$ and $f$. Finally, using:

$$\sum _{a_1=0}^{\infty } \sum _{a_2=0}^{\infty } \cdots \sum _{a_k=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{p_1^{a_1} p_2^{a_2} \cdots p_k^{a_k}}=\prod _{i=1}^k \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p_i}}$$

we obtain:

```
unrestrictedSum[p_List] := Times @@ (1/(1 - 1/p))

unrestrictedSum[{5, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23}]
```

> 96577/55296

Now, the allowed set can sometimes contain a parameter. For example:

```
allowed[{12}]
```

> (f[2] == 1 && f[3] == 0) || (f[2] == 0 && f[3] == 1) || (f[2] == 0 && 
>      f[3] == 0) || (C[1] ∈ Integers && C[1] >= 2 && f[2] == 0 && 
>      f[3] == C[1])

Here is a function that sums up the reciprocal contributions of each Or element:

```
reciprocalSums[a_Or]:=With[{logical = LogicalExpand[a]},
    Total[reciprocalSum /@ List @@ logical]
]
reciprocalSums[a_]:=reciprocalSum[a]

reciprocalSum[e_]:=Module[{fs = Cases[e, _f, Infinity] //Union, res, cs, n},
    res = m /. First @ Solve[Reduce[m == Times @@ Replace[fs, f[n_]:>n^-f[n], {1}] && e, m], m, fs];
    cs = Sequence @@ Cases[e, C[i_] >= l_ :> {n[i], l, Infinity}, Infinity];
    res /. ConditionalExpression[m_, conds_] :> Sum @@ {m /. C[i_]:>n[i], cs}
]
```

For the above example we have:

```
reciprocalSums[allowed[{12}]]
```

> 2

Or, breaking it down to pieces:

```
reciprocalSum[f[2] == 1 && f[3] == 0]
reciprocalSum[f[2] == 0 && f[3] == 1]
reciprocalSum[f[2] == 0 && f[3] == 0]
reciprocalSum[C[1] ∈ Integers && C[1] >= 2 && f[2] == 0 && f[3] == C[1]]
```

> 1/2
>
> 1/3
>
> 1
>
> 1/6

Finally, packaging up the above as a function:

```
restrictedSum[set_, p_] := Module[{a = allowed[set], r, u},
    r = Cases[a, f[q_]->q, Infinity]//Union;
    u = Complement[Prime[Range[PrimePi[p]]], r];

    reciprocalSums[a] unrestrictedSum[u]
]
```

Some examples:

```
restrictedSum[{8}, 23]
restrictedSum[{12}, 23]
restrictedSum[{25}, 23]
restrictedSum[{12 25}, 23]
restrictedSum[{12, 25}, 23]
restrictedSum[{12, 15}, 23]
```

> 676039/147456
>
> 676039/165888
>
> 676039/138240
>
> 49350847/8294400
>
> 676039/207360
>
> 676039/276480

This function should work for any set $L$. @DanielLichtblau's answer only works when the set $L$ is coprime, and in that case, my answer and his answer agree.

Comment: Take the subset {30}. The restrictions above are `{{f[2]->0,f[3]->0,f[5]->0},{f[2]->0,f[3]->0,f[5]->1},{f[2]->0,f[3]->1,f[5]->0},{f[2]->1,f[3]->0,f[5]->0}`. This does not allow a factor such as `1/2^n` for `n>1`. This is why it is giving results that are too low when given values in `L` that have three or more prime factors (counting multiplicity).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks, I see where I went wrong now. I will patch it up shortly.

Answer (score 4):

I have something, but I am unsure if it is what you are looking for or if it is even fast enough for larger values of n. Using n = 28:

```
p = Prime[PrimePi[28]]
23

sets = Subsets[Select[Range[28], CompositeQ]];
```

For testing I picked just one subset to start with:

```
set = sets[[1000]]
{4, 6, 8, 25}
```

The first condition for i is already given by you. For the second condition:

```
gcdTest[i_, subset_] := And @@ (CompositeQ[#/GCD[i, #]] & /@ subset)
```

I am basically just testing each element in the subset L with a given i, then using the logical And to pick out only the i values where this is true for all elements in L.

The 2 tests can then be used to pick out the desired i values for some given cutoff value (to avoid infinite possible i values):

```
cutoff = 1000;

iList = Select[
  Range[cutoff], (FactorInteger[#][[-1, 1]] <= p && 
     gcdTest[#, set]) &]
{1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 49, 77, 91, 119, 121, 133, 143, 161, 169,
187, 209, 221, 247, 253, 289, 299, 323, 343, 361, 391, 437, 529, 539,
637, 833, 847, 931}
```

From here we can determine the desired total:

```
N@Total[1/iList]
1.60518
```

This process could then be applied to all subsets.

I am far from an expert in mathematica, so there is probably a way better way to do this, but I thought I would take a shot.

UPDATE:
Here is a more compact version that will give a list of the specified sums for all of the subsets L rather than just one L as I have demonstrated above. Speed wise, this will take about 50 minutes to find the sums for the 262143 possible sets L when n = 28 (it takes about 3 seconds to get through about 260 of the sets).

```
gcdTest[i_, subset_] := And @@ (CompositeQ[#/GCD[i, #]] & /@ subset);

sums[n_, iMax_] :=
 Module[

  {p = Prime[PrimePi[n]],
   sets = Subsets[Select[Range[28], CompositeQ]][[2 ;;]]
   },

  Table[Total[1/#] &
    [Select[
     Range[iMax], (FactorInteger[#][[-1, 1]] <= p && 
        gcdTest[#, sets[[a]]]) &]]
   , {a, Length@sets}]
  ]
```

Comment: We did almost the same thing. I'm quite confident this is the way to go, even if I'm not an expert at all. I'm totally upvoting you.

Answer (score 3):

Straightforward implementation. First, some definitions:

```
n = 4;
p = Prime[PrimePi[n]];
imax = 10;
L = Subsets[Select[Range[n], CompositeQ]];

set = Select[Range[imax], (FactorInteger[#][[-1, 1]] <= p) && (And @@ 
  Table[CompositeQ[j/GCD[#, j]], {j, Flatten@L}]) &]

(* {1, 3, 9} *)
```

Now, the sum is trivial to implement:

```
Sum[1/i, {i, set}]
(* 13/9 *)
```

Is this the expected output?

Comment: Impressive, but very clear approach. Wow.

Comment: From what I understand, the L defined by the OP is actually the elements of what you define L to be. The OP wants a sum for each of these elements. From what I can tell, this method doesn't consider these elements separately due to the Flatten function.

Comment: @AaronStevens You do have a point. The OP is slightly ambiguous IMHO. I left a comment asking for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

[Not a complete answer, sorry.]

There is a fairly simple-to-code way to handle the (very) special case of subsets of one element, and a straightforward extension for when the set is all pairwise coprime.

First the singleton case. Suppose `plist` is the set of primes up to the cutoff. The unrestricted sum of all produc-of-reciprocal-prime-powers is `Product[1/(1 - 1/pj), {pj, plist}]`. Given another integer `n`, from this unrestricted sum certain summands need to be removed in a way that involves the prime factorization of `n` (this is to support requirement #2). It amounts to carving out infinite rectangular regions in the integer lattice of integer powers e.g. if a term in the unrestricted sum is `1/p1^e1*1/p2^e2*...*1/pk^ek then the lattice point is {e1,e2,...,ek}. I won't try to explain in detail why this works, but it involves removing first a rectangle that is infinite in all dimensions involving prime factors of`n`, then removing pieces that are each infinite in one less dimension (each corresponding to one particular prime factor).

```
sum[n_, plist_] := Module[{fax = FactorInteger[n], flist, prod},
  prod = Product[1/(1 - 1/pj), {pj, plist}];
  flist = fax[[All, 1]];
  (1 - 1/n)*prod - Sum[p/n*prod*(1 - 1/p), {p, flist}]]
```

Example: We have the subset {12} and we are working with maximum prime of 23.

```
s12 = sum[12, Prime[Range[9]]]

(* Out[2126]= 676039/165888 *)

N[s12]

(* Out[2127]= 4.07527367863 *)
```

Here are a few more examples. They might be compared to some of the more general methods already presented.

```
Map[sum[#, Prime[Range[9]]] &, {8, 12, 14, 25, 12*25, 12*35}] // N

(* Out[2133]= {4.58468288845, 4.07527367863, 2.6198187934, \
4.89032841435, 5.94989957079, 5.90914683401} *)
```

When the set is pairwise coprime one can basically iterate the method of carving away some semiinfinite rectangles.

```
sumCoprimes[nlist_, plist_] /; Apply[CoprimeQ, nlist] := 
 Module[{res, nj, fax, flist},
  res = Product[1/(1 - 1/pj), {pj, plist}];
  Do[nj = nlist[[j]];
   fax = FactorInteger[nj];
   flist = fax[[All, 1]];
   res = ((1 - 1/nj) - Sum[p/nj*(1 - 1/p), {p, flist}])*res;
   , {j, Length[nlist]}];
  res
  ]
```

Examples:

```
sumCoprimes[{12, 25}, Prime[Range[9]]] // N

(* Out[2150]= 3.2602189429 *)

sumCoprimes[{12, 25, 7^2*11}, Prime[Range[9]]] // N

(* Out[2151]= 3.15739200036 *)
```

If ever I figure out how to lift the coprimality assumption and extend to the general case, e.g. by inclusion-exclusion, I'll post an update. I thought even without that it might be useful to have an exact method for this special case.